# Unexpected Content type in response on using Java RestAssured

Tags: content-type, rest-assured

I had set Content-Type in RequestSpecBuilder as "ContentType.JSON". But on making a GET request, I get Content-Type as  "application/xml" in response. How do i get  back a json response?
I have tried below approaches:
1. Set content type in RequestSpecBuilder object using setContentType method of RequestSpecBuilder class to "ContentType.JSON" and pass RequestSpecBuilder object in spec method of RequestSpecification --- got "application/xml" in response

2. Set content type in RequestSpecification object using contentType method of RequestSpecification  and pass ContentType.JSON as parameter --- still got "application/xml" in response

Note: The webservice URL requires ".json" to be explicitly specified to get a json response else by default it returns a "xml" response. However, I wanted to set content type by using RequestSpecBuilder.
Eg: 
for Json response: URL -- http://ergast.com/api/f1/2017/circuits.json
for Xml response: URL -- http://ergast.com/api/f1/2017/circuits

```
Code:
@Test   
public void test_AddHeader() {      
        //Use of RequestSpecification
        String pathUrl = "http://ergast.com/api/f1/2017/circuits";
        RequestSpecBuilder requestSpecBuilder = new RequestSpecBuilder();
        requestSpecBuilder = requestSpecBuilder.        
                setBaseUri(pathUrl).
                setContentType(ContentType.JSON).
                addQueryParam("limit", "10"); //added query param       
        RequestSpecification addRequestSpec = requestSpecBuilder.build();       

        RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given().spec(addRequestSpec).contentType(ContentType.JSON);      
        Response httpResponse = httpRequest.get();
        System.out.println(httpResponse.getContentType()); //returns application/xml
        System.out.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine());   //returns HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        System.out.println(httpResponse.getBody().asString());//returns XML response
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting `JSON` from Response but you are passing `setContentType` to your `RequestSpecBuilder`. This will just create your POST payload in json format. It does not do anything to your response.

What you can do instead is Create a `ResponseBuilder` and do a `setContentType` to JSON there. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I added a filter to RequestSpecification and overrode filter method which returns Response as a parameter as shown below. But request failed at httprequest.get(). 
Filter filter = new Filter(){
  @Override
   public Response filter(FilterableRequestSpecification requestSpec,
     FilterableResponseSpecification responseSpec, FilterContext ctx) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new ResponseBuilder().setContentType(ContentType.JSON).build();
   }   
  };  
  RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given().spec(addRequestSpec).filter(filter);

Comment: What is the need of a filter here. Just create a simple ResponseBuilder, that might solve your purpose. Filters also tend to alter the request.

Comment: I was able to clone the original response using responseBuilder and setContentType to JSon but still the response body remained in xml. This is the syntax: new ResponseBuilder().clone(originalHttpResponse).setContentType(ContentType.JSON).build(); How do i change the response body to JSon?